# Questions about STM32l052 LCD data port

Tags: stm32

```
#include "lcd.h"
#define data (GPIOA((uint16_t)0x8000U)) | (GPIOB((uint16_t)0x00FBU))
void LCD_Clear(void) {
GPIOC->BRR = ((uint16_t)0x4000U); // RS LOW
data&0x38; HAL_Delay(10); // Function Set 8bit, 2 Line, 5x7 Dots
data&0x01; HAL_Delay(10); // Clear
GPIOC->BSRR = ((uint16_t)0x4000U); // RS HIGH
}
```

I wrote the code as above.
The LCD data pins are connected as shown below.
D0 // A15, D1 //  B0, D2 // B1, D3 // B3, D4 // B4, D5 // B5, D6 // B6, D7 // B7
`
Running the code gives me the following error: How can I put the pins I want in DATA?
error image

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a quite untypical question. You should make some fundamental exercises on using C language in embedded projects. You can in principle do this on your STM32 as well as on many other microcontrollers - just try to program a flashing LED and/or reading in a push button or so. Then you will learn how to control the pins of your MCU, and using peripherals for the more compilicated jobs isn't that far away any more.

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, it is not possible to set GPIOA and GPIOB pins the way you did.

There a multiple problems with this line:

`#define data (GPIOA((uint16_t)0x8000U)) | (GPIOB((uint16_t)0x00FBU))`

- GPIOA and GPIOB are pointers. Using logic operators on them is not a common use case
- a #define macro is basically a text-based preprocessor operation. When you do `data&0x38` you do  `(GPIOA((uint16_t)0x8000U)) | (GPIOB((uint16_t)0x00FBU))&0x38` which makes no sense at all and leads to the error depicted (as GPIOA/B are pointers to typedefs)

Assuming you want to set or reset GPIO pins, you must:

- Enable the port clock (I assume you didn't)
- Set or Reset pins with e.g. `GPIOA->BSRR |= BIT1` and `GPIOA->BRR |= BIT2`
- Define "BIT" Macros for your register with `#define BIT1 1 << 1U`, `#define BIT2 1 << 2U`, `#define BIT3 1 << 3U` and so on